# EOF error encountered while converting bytearray to bitmapdata

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, bitmapimage

I am using

```
var bitmapdata:BitmapData=new BitmapData();
var pixels:Bytearray=new Bytearray();
pixels = rleDecodePixles();
bitmapdata.setPixels(bitmapdata.rect, pixels);
```

In the 4th line in the code above i am getting "Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered." I checked the **length** of the *pixels* object which is 4 times the **width*height** of the *rect* object. Given that **setPixels()** functions reads unsigned int from bytearray and sets that value to pixels, I think it should work.

But I have no clue why this wont work. The *pixels* object is filled after RLE decoding of the data which i get from a server.

Is there any work around or any other method which I could try to use. The loader class wont work as the data that I get from the server is not in any of the recognized format.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Shrikant

Thanks.

Comment: Are you encoding the alpha channel really server side ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Could you please elaborate on the alpha channel thing. The image data that i get is for a mouse cursor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get the EOF error from ByteArray when you try to move its pointer beyond the last position available. When you fill your ByteArray, you actually move its pointer, so before you can do anything with it, you have to reset it's position.

Try :

```
var bitmapdata:BitmapData=new BitmapData();
var pixels:Bytearray=new Bytearray();
pixels = rleDecodePixles();
pixels.position = 0; // Reset ByteArray pointer
bitmapdata.setPixels(bitmapdata.rect, pixels);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Still getting "End of file was encountered", and the ByteArray has the right length of my image file: 58384 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Also I just found out that the following code works:

```
bitmap.object.setPixels(bitmap.object.rect, bitmap.createPixels(width, height));

function creatPixels(width:int,height:int):Bytearray
{
   var result:Bytearray=new Bytearray();
    result.length=(width*height)<<2;
    return result;
}
```

But after i have modified the bytearray and then try to set the pixels it throws the aforementioned error. 
even more confused now.

Comment: looks like the position of bytearray was set to non zero value and hence bytes available were less than required. fixing the position to zero solved it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've posted an answer before I noticed you had found the solution.